# it still loading when i type ruby command, doesn't display anything

Tags: ruby

my problem is when I type this command: `ruby`

It still no working, 
it doesn't display anything, 
loading for long time!!

how can I solve this problem??

Regards

Comment: as others have said this is by design (waiting for input), but curious what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not loading. `ruby` interpreter is waiting for your code.

Use `irb` if you want an interactive interface to run short code with.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just run a simple command use the `-e` argument and pass it code in parenthesis.

`ruby -e "puts 'hello'"`

However, like others have pointed out, 99% of the time you are better off running `irb` which opens up an interactive prompt.

Answer (score 1):

That's what is supposed to happen. Use `irb` command for Ruby REPL (prompt) and `ruby file.rb` to run Ruby code in files.